# I am getting an error while executing a simple try catch block example :" a cannot be resolved to a variable"

Tags: exception

```
public class ex2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        try
        {
            String s= a[0];
            int x = Integer.parseInt(x);
            System.out.println("val of x = " +x);
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException nfe)
        {
            System.err.println("Enter numeric value");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change these two:

- `String s= a[0];` to `String s = args[0];`
- `int x = Integer.parseInt(x);` to `int x = Integer.parseInt(s);`

The error means that in the line `String s= a[0];`, it expects a variable (a String array) called `a`, which does not exist.